# Android compatibilty settings in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play, screen-size

I have an app to release which works on all android screen-sizes (except smaller) and densities above SDK version 2.0.

It will also run on extra large screens. 
Currently I have added this:

```
<supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:anyDensity="true" 
    />
```

But I also need to add `android:xlargeScreens="true"` , to allow it visible in android market on extra large screen devices, since by default it is false.

But to add `android:xlargeScreens` I need to change my eclipse targetsettings to 2.3 as this attribute was added from API level 9.

So what should I do with my target compilation settings for this scenario ? Should it be 2.3 while compiling ? If yes, then will the app not give any problems while running on devices with 2.0 version ?

Comment: Concluding on discussions below it seems , just to add android:xlargeScreens="true" in manifest I will have to change my whole project target in properties to API level 9 and compile and distribute ? This will no way harm for build running on all lower versions ? I had already set <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" /> <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion = "8"/> in the manifest And currently I have set my eclipse project target platform to 2.0 in its properties, as this is the mimimum level I need to support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While reading [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/preparing-for-handsets.html) blog post I guess I have an answer on my old question. An extract below (which is for another manifest attribute "requiresSmallestWidthDp" introduced from 3.2):

"The catch is that you must compile your application against Android 3.2 or higher in order to use the requiresSmallestWidthDp attribute. Older versions don’t understand this attribute and will raise a compile-time error. The safest thing to do is develop your app against the platform that matches the API level you’ve set for minSdkVersion. When you’re making final preparations to build your release candidate, change the build target to Android 3.2 and add the requiresSmallestWidthDp attribute. Android versions older than 3.2 simply ignore that XML attribute, so there’s no risk of a runtime failure."

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need to change the uses sdk to 2.3 but make sure that you are not using any newer apis which are not in 2.0 or whatever your minimum supported sdk version is. Or in case you want to use them you have to use reflection.

But [more about how to use the sdk versions is here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html) and [more about uses-sdk is here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html).

I do the same in my application and make sure you test your application in both[all] the versions before you release.

Best,
Achie.

Comment: Yes we can do that but will not compiling with newer APIs will break the app somewhere on older devices meaning --- although the API is supported from older version , but its implementation is overriden (may be optimized) in newer 2.3 version which calls a method that did not existed in older version.

Comment: @Pritam no that will not happen. If the api existed (and therefore included in the Android OS code on the device) it will execute exactly as before, no optimizations can be made to old api's without a firmware upgrade.

Comment: No it will not. Newer methods if available will be used in newer apis but since you will not be using them, you cannot break stuff because of them. ANd if newer apis do have a better implementation then the device running on newer version will have the appropriate code to run it.

Comment: @smith324 I would like to be a bit more clearer what I mean. My concern is suppose a method named func1() is added in API level 1, and enhanced/optimized in API level 9 using some other func_new that came along with 9, so for us we still use func1() and while compiling with library 2.3 it will go well. But actually when running on lower device, its actual output .dex file will fail as the compiled code is using newer func_new() not supported on device.

Comment: for arguments sake say the func1() is available on the device in concern now. So lets say the devices on 2.3 may call new func_new from inside func1() of sdk. But why would this break if the device running on 1.6 does not have func_new. they have an alternative implementation for func1().

Comment: @Pritam If you mean that func_new() is a sub routine of func1() then the .dex file shouldn't contain a reference to func_new() at all. When you compile against new frameworks you are not bundling those frameworks with your application, they are already present on the device. (Also targeting API level 1 is a losing battle, I'd suggest 3 or 4)

Comment: @achie so nothing happens on compile level ? As we compile using 2.3 library I assumed its bytecode(assume java for timebeing) would have calls for newer functions written inside the expansion of inline code. Later this installed on device would stuck ? May be its wrong.. So in general , we can say that we always set our Eclipse to latest target while generating output file ? Just test first with your minimum target to catch Errors, and then once done Reset the target to latest and compile the output. Thanks all for the answers.

Comment: @smith324 Thanks .. I think I got it. So will the assumption for Eclipse environment made in my above comment will always work ?

Comment: At the compile level it should check for the existence of the method and the functionality but it should stop at the method call. What might be even better though for your other question regarding testing, incase you are in doubt if you are using newer apis is to write the code and build it using the older sdk and once everything is working you can build it against newer target. What you said regarding minimum version and eclipse should work too. But make sure you test it on a emulator/device.

Comment: I saw problems in 1.5 devices though but thats not due to the problem that we are talking about. Its because prior to 1.6 there was support for only one screen size and 1.5 devices look for resources in drawable folder and not drawable-[hdpi/mdpi/ldpi] folders. So if we support 1.5 also then we need to put all out resources from drawable-mdpi into the drawable directory.

Comment: My response wouldn't fit in a comment haha, check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm moving this from the comments to make it more clear for others looking at this question in the future.

When supporting both old and new versions of Android it can be confusing how applications manage to run despite many things change with in the frameworks during each new release, I'm going to try and clarify this here.

An application written for the 1.5 sdk can only call functions that exist for that API level, so for instance the multi touch api's didn't exist in 1.5 and never will. Now you say "Ok but I don't need to call any newer APIs, I just want my app to work in 2.3 and have a2sd support" And I say "Ok, just change your targetApi in the manifest, set the minSDK and compile against 2.3 and you're good to go."

Now why does that work? What if the onMeasure() method for `ListView` was changed in 2.2 and now calls betterCalculateFunction() within onMeasure()? Why does my app still work?

This is the advantage of late binding in Java. You see, Java is never compiled until it reaches a device and is running, what you are doing in Eclipse is converting it to byte code which contains a bunch of byte code instructions that are later interpreted by the device. The byte code will NEVER contain a reference to betterCalculateFunction() though (unless you directly call it. Calling onMeasure() is indirect). This can happen because when your code is running on the device it gets linked against the Android framework on the device and your code calls onMeasure() directly because it is a public outward facing API. The path of execution will then enter the framework and call whatever it needs to, then once its done return to your code.

> So on 1.5 you might see
>
> doStuff (your code) -> onMeasure
>   (public API) -> done
>
> and 2.2
>
> doStuff (your code) -> onMeasure
>   (public API) ->
>   betterCalculateFunction (private
>   function) ->done

Now if you need to call functions that may or may not exist depending on API level then I suggest you look at a related answer of mine here [stackoverflow: gracefully downgrade your app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526813/how-to-downgrade-my-android-app-from-2-2-to-1-5-sdk-seamlessly/4527854#4527854)

Hope that clears some things up.

Comment: Thanks. So concluding on the original question, just to add android:xlargeScreens="true" in manifest I will have to change my whole project target in properties to API level 9 and compile and distribute ? This will no way harm for build running on all lower versions ?

Comment: I had already set <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" />
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion = "8"/> in the manifest And currently I have set my eclipse project target platform to 2.0 in its properties, as this is the mimimum level I need to support.

Comment: @Pritam Yes, but please test it on the minSdk emulator first. Your users will thank you for it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried 2.3, but that's what I do with 2.2.

I compile for 2.2 and test on 1.6 to make sure everything works how I'm expecting. I haven't run in to any issues with it.

To double check, set your target for 2.3 and then setup an emulator for a lower rev version to make sure it all works.

Comment: If we set target to 2.3 and compile , in run configuration we cannot see avd (emulators) that are below 2.3 in eclipse.

Comment: @Pritam: start the emulator you want using the AVD Manager. Then set up your run configuration to manually select the deployment target and select the running emulator when it prompts. That's how you can run on a 2.1 emulator with a project set to 2.3.

Comment: Pritam, you need to use the uses-sdk tag and define the minSdkVersion that you want to support. Have a look at the links in my answer.

Comment: @Ted Hopp Thanks for this. Actually instead of this I had tested on actual device, but my concern is for below comment for @achie.

Comment: @Ted Hopp Thanks for answering so quick!
@Pritam - Check Archie's answer, that should get you where you need to go!

Answer (score 0):

The default value for android:xlargeScreens is true, so you don't have to change anything - it's on by default, as long as your minSdkVersion or targetSdkVersion is higher than 4.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Comment: Well it seems there is contradiction/error in the online docs. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html here it states that -- Default value is "true" only when minSdkVersion or targetSdkVersion is 9 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an official Android developer blog explanation of how this works:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html

In summary: you can use the newest XML whilst still supporting the older OS versions in a back compatible way.

Answer (score -1):

For different screens you have to create multiple apk then it reduces size of your application.In each application's manifest you have to define  according to following link.
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html